# call react script on button click with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have a react script that I need to it to be loaded when a button is clicked so i created a function with jquery that catches the click button and then loades the react script like this

```
$('#but').on('click', function(){
  $.getScript("/static/39f3e10/js/loadxb.jsx", function (data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
    console.log(data);
    console.log(textStatus);
    console.log(jqxhr.status);
    console.log("file is loaded");
  });
});
```

when i click the button the script gets loaded successfuly but it does not execute, that means that the react script doesn't render render a component inside a div, I'm not getting any errors by the way on the console

Answer (score 0):

this won't function because the browser can't execute a JSX script. It has to be parsed by React and then it runs scripts that interpret it and uses the template.

I'm sorry to give you a "you're doing it wrong" answer, but essentially you can't / shouldn't use Jquery to execute a JSX file. You should include the react template in your main react app and then if you really do want to make something happen via a button click then you would call a method on your app. But generally, mixing Jquery in in this way isn't advised.

Comment: what if I compiled the jsx script into js script and then call it with  will it work `$.getScript()` ?

Comment: Sure, you'd also have to bundle the whole of React in the script, presumably. Not sure what your overall plan is here, but I'd advise rethinking this and doing it "the React way". But that's just opinion.